# How can I change the white background in the file manager?

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, themes, gtk

I would like to change the white background of my file manager. *(I really searched everywhere and tried a lot of things.)*

I was trying to change **CSS files** of my theme **(GTK2 & GTK3 folders)** and I tried others themes too, but no luck so far.

I wish to change the *"eye-killing"* white to grey, In Windows you could just change that easily with the theme changer.

In Xubuntu (**I'm using XFCE**), this seems impossible.I switched back to Ubuntu, but there I couldn't change this, even they’re using same principles.

[image]

Could anyone give me a hint where I change this annoying white background?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try to change the **"gtk_color_scheme"** (gtk-2)  or **"default color scheme"**(gtk-3) defined in the **"gtkrc"** or **"gtk.css"** files of your theme.

AS [vasa1](https://askubuntu.com/users/25656/vasa1) explains in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287270/how-to-change-gtk3-color-scheme-on-ubuntu-13-04/287361#287361) answer, there are advantages to keep the themes in you `~/.themes` folder.
Because will be user-specific and not system-wide and you do not need `sudo` to edit them.

Here you have an example.

*In this case I'm running Xubuntu 13.04 with the default them "Greybird".
I only edit the gtkrc file (gtk-2) because Thunar (As far as I know) is a gtk-2 application.*

**1)** Open a Terminal window and type:

- `sudo mousepad /usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

Search for the line nuber 6, and change the **base_color** from **#fcfcfc** to **#CECECE**

[image]

**BEFORE:**

> gtk_color_scheme  =
>   "bg_color:#CECECE\nselected_bg_color:#398ee7\nbase_color:#fcfcfc" #
>   Background, base.

**AFTER:**

> gtk_color_scheme  =
>   "bg_color:#CECECE\nselected_bg_color:#398ee7\nbase_color:#CECECE" #
>   Background, base.

**2)** Logout and Login to see the changes.

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]

Also you can edit the file **gtk.css** for the (gtk-3) applications.

- `sudo mousepad /usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

You can change the **@define-color base_color** from **#fcfcfc** to **#CECECE**

**NOTE:** This is just an example, please change the settings according to your needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @vasa1...thanks for your suggestion. I edited my answer. Please feel free to add new info or edit the answer.

Comment: You may already know about this but Xubuntu 13.10 will bring a GUI to make at least some changes to themes without users having to edit theme files by hand: [A new tool to change your theme colors, gtk-theme-config (not installed by default, yet)](http://xubuntu.org/news/saucy-salamander-b1/). It's already available but not from the Software Center. It's been made by one of the [Shimmer theme authors](http://satya164.deviantart.com/journal/GTK-theme-preferences-Customize-GTK-themes-325890045).

Comment: Roman Raguet, I just don't know how to thank you for your excellent step-by-step post. I wished I have more reputation to give you points for this. Your post inspired me to help others with questions/problems, when I've gained any experience with my new Ubuntu/Debian system.

Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to Help. @vasa1 gave us useful information for the post.

Comment: Perhaps you know where I can find the settings for [url=http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/?p=198]Nemo[/url]. 

I changed the GTK2.0, without results. But I cannot find another settings of Nemo.

Comment: following the same example.. xubuntu 13.04 , Greybird theme, but with nemo instead of thunar. you should edit the /usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-3.0/gtk.css file (nemo is GTK3) and You can change the @define-color base_color from #fcfcfc to #CECECE. about theming maybe this links could help you.
http://worldofgnome.org/making-gtk3-themes-part-1-basics/ , 
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/customize-gtk3-gtk2-theme-colors-using.html

Comment: Roman, please... tell me how I could thank you? :-)

Comment: no problem.. Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

I found a great answer in another post [How do I change to a theme not listed in the Appearance screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-to-a-theme-not-listed-in-the-appearance-screen)

oh, and this still applies to ubuntu 16.04, which I have running...

just install gnome-tweak-tool and my newly installed dark themes were there (or whatever non-white bkgd themes you choose to install), they apply to thunar, nautilus, system monitor bkgds...... phew.....