# How to apply numix color to the folder background?

Tags: 14.04, numix

I've recently installed numix-folders, numix-gtk-theme, and numix-icon-theme. Everything looks great except for the folder background color which is white by default. I wish I could apply the same **numix theme** to the folder background. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a solution, and I'll post it just in case someone has had the same problem. I found most of the answer from this post [How can I change the white background in the file manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345648/how-can-i-change-the-white-background-in-the-file-manager)
But I had to go to /usr/share/themes/**Numix**/gtk-3.0/gtk.css.
Then, change base_color to the numix theme color(#2d2d2d). 
Hope this helps.